# Display post if a specific tag is present

Tags: tags, conditional-content

I want to display a particular message when a post has a specific tag on the article.

I've done this, however the 'Hello' text is being shown no matter if the post has the tag 'test' or not.

```
<?php if ( has_tag() == 'test' ) : ?>

    Hello

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're using `has_tag` wrong. You should be attempting `has_tag('test')` in your if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/) the input parameters can be:

```
has_tag( string|int|array $tag = '', int|object $post = null )
```

so you could try e.g.

```
if( has_tag( 'test' ) ) { ... }
```

to check if the current post has the *test* tag.

Comment: ps: I should also mention that `has_tag()` is boolean, i.e. only returns `true` or `false`.